# SerialPort ReadLine() after Thread.Sleep() goes crazy

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, serial-port

I've been fighting with this issue for a day and I can't find answer for it.
I am trying to read data from GPS device trough COM port in Compact Framework C#. I am using SerialPort class (actually my own ComPort class boxing SerialPort, but it adds only two fields I need, nothing special).

Anyway, I am running while loop in a separate thread which reads line from the port, analyze NMEA data, print them, catch all exceptions and then I Sleep(200) the thread, because I need CPU for other threads... Without Sleep it works fine, but uses 100% CPU.. When I don't use Sleep after few minutes the output from COM port looks like this:

> GPGSA,A,3,09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   GSA,A,3,09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   A,A,3,09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   ,18,12,271,24,24,05,020,24,14,04,326,25,11,03,023,*76
>   A,3,09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   3,09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   09,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F
>   ,12,22,17,15,27,,,,,,,2.6,1.6,2.1*3F

as you can see the same message is read few times but **cut**.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong...
My port configuration:

```
port.ReadBufferSize = 4096;  
port.BaudRate = 4800;  
port.DataBits = 8;  
port.Parity = Parity.None;  
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;  
port.NewLine = "\r\n";  
port.ReadTimeout = 1000;  
port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 100000;
```

And my reading function:

```
private void processGps(){  
    while (!closing)   
    {  
        //reconnect if needed
        try  
        {  
            string sentence = port.ReadLine();  
            //here print the sentence  
            //analyze the sentence (this takes some time 50-100ms)  
        }  
        catch (TimeoutException)  
        {  
            Thread.Sleep(0);  
        }  
        catch (IOException ioex)  
        {  
            //handling IO exception (some info on the screen)  
        }  
    Thread.Sleep(200);  
    }  
}
```

There is some more stuff in this function like reconnection if the device is lost etc., but it is not called when the GPS is connected properly. I was trying

```
port.DiscardInBuffer();
```

after some blocks of code (in TimeoutException, after read.)

Did anyone had similar problem? I really dont know what I'm doing wrong.. The only way to get rig of it is removing the last Sleep.

Comment: Have you considered async operations instead of sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

For all those who have similar problem. The first issue was about overflowing the buffer. I had 4096 size of buffer and the data was just flowing trough it so I was reading corrupted sentences. Now I read all buffer at once and analyze it. First sentence is sometimes corrupted, but the rest is ok.
The second thing was the device issue. Tom Tom MkII sometimes loses connection with the device. I had to restart the GPS and find it again in Bt devices list.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your post to say how you are doing handshaking.

Normally you would use software (XON/XOFF) or hardware (e.g. RTS/CTS) handshaking so that the serial port will tell the transmitting to stop when it is unable to receive more data.  The handshaking configuration must (of course) match the configuration of the transmitting device.

If you fail to configure handshaking correctly, you may get away with it as long as you are processing the data fast enough - but when you have a Sleep, data may be lost.